# Number to String (Always 2 decimal Place)

Tags: c#, format

I want to show a double value to label (C#) with 2 decimal places no matters that value like 13 or 13.5 or 13.505
Its always show 13.00

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Can you give a short but complete example?

Comment: What is the expected output 13.00?

Comment: yeah.. expected output is 13.00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this method

```
double i=12.22222;             //first variable
double j=1.2545;              //second variable
double h=i*j;                 // multiple first and second
string s=h.ToString("0.00");  // convert to string and proper format
```

this methed return

```
s="15.33"
```

Comment: But If value of h is 15 then i want to 15.00 as output

Comment: then u add this also string[] st=s.Split('.');
            if (st.Length > 0)
            {
                s = s;
            }
            else
            {
                s = s + ".00";
            }

Answer (score 13):

You can pass the format in to the to string method

eg:

```
ToString("0.00"); //2dp Number

ToString("n2"); // 2dp Number

ToString("c2"); // 2dp currency
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

To change, for example, 13.505 to 13.00 you'd also want to run it through Math.Floor or use one of the other suggested methods for rounding down.

```
Math.Floor(value)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx

If, on the other hand, you want to change 13.505 to 13.50 you'd want to run it through Math.Truncate.

```
Math.Truncate(Value)
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So to tie that together:

```
Double testValue = 13.505;
Double testValueTruncated = Math.Truncate(100 * testValue) / 100;
string withDecimalPlaces = testValueTruncated.ToString("0.00");
```

withDecimalPlaces will now have the value "13.50"

Comment: I added an example. In what way is it not working?

Comment: In 13.505, output must be 13.50, not 13.00

13.00 in only those case where value like 13 or 13.0

If 13.1 the output will be 13.10. I hope, now everything clear.

Comment: Ah I see, from your question I, and I think others, took it to mean that whatever the value, 13 or 13.5 or 13.505 that you wanted it to always show 13.00.